# Discrete Mathematics and the Laws of Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this laws of logic question where it requires me to distribute stuff into brackets but no matter how many times I do it I keep getting it wrong because my distributing is done wrong.

Q:

Simplify $(\neg q \vee p) \wedge (\neg p \wedge r)$

The answer to this is $\neg p \wedge \neg q \wedge r$

Can someone please show me the steps to how to expand and simplify this problem? It's clearly not the same as normal expansion in everyday math, which is why I keep getting it wrong because there must be some special expansion method for these problems.

Edit:

Are we allowed to just expand the negate p into the (negate q or p) without having to expand the r in as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use distributive laws and associative laws

$a \land (b \lor c) \leftrightarrow (a\land b) \lor (a \land c)$

$a \lor (b \land c) \leftrightarrow (a \lor b) \land (a \lor c)$

$a \land (b \land c) \leftrightarrow (a \land b) \land c$

$a \lor (b \lor c) \leftrightarrow (a \lor b) \lor c$

So

$(\neg q \lor p) \land (\neg p \land r) \leftrightarrow ((\neg q \lor p) \land \neg p) \land r \leftrightarrow (( \neg q \land \neg p) \lor (p \land \neg p))  \land r$ (1)

But since $ \vdash \neg (p \land \neg p)$, for all $p$ we have that 
$(( \neg q \land \neg p) \lor (p \land \neg p)) \leftrightarrow \neg q \land \neg p$
hence sentence (1) is equivalent to

$( \neg q \land \neg p)  \land r$